# How can I reward my cat besides using edible treats?

Tags: behavior, cats, treats

One of my cats is completely non-responsive to edible treats. Be it salmon, chicken or beef flavored, he completely ignores any treats I give him.

I want to be able to reward him/get him to come when I shake a bag of treats, but can't figure out any way to do this without edible treats, since he does not respond to praise like a dog.

What alternative ways are there to reward cats?

Comment: Are you wanting to reward him for a certain behavior or just as a general thing because he's your pet?

Comment: If you feed dry food, have you attempted to give him dry food kibbles as treats? Since he already recognizes them as food, he may respond to them.

Comment: I want to reward him for good behavior. Ie. Using a scratching post. And I've tried using dry food, but he recognizes that it's just his normal food and snubs it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both of my cats (mother and daughter) have a fondness for catnip.  Like typical dry treats, shaking the packaging it comes in will make a noise your cat should be able to hear without difficulty.

The mother cat has a fondness for wet cat food, but will not eat dried fish treats (though she is very interested in the smell).  Her daughter is the exact opposite:  loves dried fish treats but will not touch wet cat food.

Keep in mind that the treat doesn't need to make a noise if all you want to do is teach your cat to come when called.  Many cats associate the sound of a can opener with food and will come running any time they hear it, even when it isn't their designated meal time.  Personally, I like "here kitty kitty" since it can be heard from very far away.

## Non-food options

My cats also respond to the sound of patting my hand on the top of their scratching post.  This is already a place that they like to be.  They've come to associate that noise with lots of petting, so all I have to do is say their name when I do it and they will come running.

You could also to try a brush for your cat.  Mine absolutely love being brushed so much that they'll tolerate being near my dog (I got him a year ago and the cats are still standoffish towards him).

Comment: Yes, my cat loves being brushed.